# How many concurrent logins from the same account does Django support?

Tags: django, authentication

I found several questions about restricting concurrent multiple logins from the same user in Django but what I am looking for is the opposite. I want to have a "generic guest" user that several people can login with and have access to specific functionality. Is there an actual limit? Do you see any major problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

If your asking about multiple users sharing the same account or even session, this is a very bad idea. Have you looked at [django-guest](http://code.google.com/p/django-guest/)? It allows guest user accounts and is what your looking for. It provides two decorators, `guest_allowed` and `login_required` which can be applied to your views. So a user can view as a 'generic guest' while you still have some control and can track them.

Also Django has `class models.AnonymousUser' but this is just a status given to users not logged in and maybe be what your after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot use django-guest because I don't want the users to be deleted afterwards since they might create data in the database associated with their account.

Comment: you can always give the user an option of becoming a 'real' user and this will tidy up the redundant data for you if they don't. Its also a good starting point for you, for could remove/override any features as needed.

Comment: also if you have the same login from the same account how do you know who the data belongs to? It's impossible (well difficult) and not a good idea.

Comment: My question was indeed for multiple users sharing the same account. Can you explain as to why this is a bad idea? the guest user does not have any functionality to update the user account model.

Comment: I am not concerned to which user the data belongs to. To put that in context for you, it is an anonymous questionnaire but requires users to know the credentials to have access to it.

Comment: it maybe anonymous but why share one account? what if a user want to 'continue the survey later'? how do you identify one data set to another for stats and data? If its just a anonymous form don't use  a login or a shared account, only bad things can happen, (sessions, users being logged out etc). You can let users login as a guess but each guess account needs to be contained on its on like in the  django-guest app. I would question why you even need to use authentication?

Comment: "requires users to know the credentials to have access" - have an access key, a survey password then.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It's not a linear survey. Users can just login to have access to the survey and post their replies.. But you are right. Due to session problems and logout issues this should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

Create a multi paged form.

1. Page 1 - Survey Password (validator/clean method to make sure that the password entered is valid)
2. Page 2 - Survey Questions

Use Django's Form Wizard: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

the wizard shows page 1 and wont let the user get to page 2 until the user answers page 1 correctly (ie password). That way users cannot get to the survey unless they have a valid password.

This solution doesn't use django's auth and should get you around all the session stuff thats blocking you from moving forward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I cannot use forms for the purpose I want. The way I will solve this is to put custom checks when the view is opened and depending on the data ask for credentials.